# Problems Using Qt 5 with OS X and GCC

Tags: macos, qt, gcc, qt5

I've been using Qt for several months now with no problems.  I originally downloaded the Qt 4.8 library with the most recent Qt Creator as of summer 2012, and I was able to start constructing my application.  My application has demanding graphics needs, so I've been using the great windowing context Qt provides for OpenGL.

I've been slowly building my skills. I have explored programable shaders with success, and I wanted to leverage the power of Geometry Shaders.  I am running OS X 10.7.5 on a MacBookPro6,2 with a GeForce GT 330M GPU.  According to what I've read from others here, the upgrade to OS X Lion included a driver to run this GPU under the OpenGL 3.2 Core Specification, including support for programable Geometry Shaders.  I also read here that while Qt 4.8 did not support OpenGL 3.2 on OS X, this support was included in their recent release of Qt 5.

I saw that Digia had also released an update to Qt Creator, so (being a little too excited for this potential breakthrough in my work) I uninstalled Qt and downloaded the Qt 5.0.0 library + Qt Creator 2.6.1.  I went through the steps in the wizard, started up the new Qt Creator and now nothing works, haha.  I have developed a love-hate relationship with my compiler and the cryptic messages it gives me, but this is different.  The errors that are being thrown make it sound like it doesn't know how to read the code any more (just to pick one example out of several hundred errors "#include ").  The wizard installed Qt fine, and all the guts are there, but I think the link to my gcc compiler has somehow been broken.  Not even the examples that came with Qt 5 compile.

Qt has introduced a new "kit" paradigm to make developing on multiple platforms easier, and I have made efforts to change the setup of the kit.  Qt detects several gcc compiler options, which I have tried, and I have manually pointed it to the path I get from the terminal command:
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

It appears to be gcc 4.2.  I see that the most current version is gcc 4.7, but I have the most  up-to-date version XCode provides.  I also downloaded "Command Line Tools" from XCode and restarted, but it did not remedy my problems as magically as I had hoped.  I am trying to update gcc manually, but I'm running into issues because it is asking me to update gmp and mpfr as well, and they are not fully cooperating.

Since the kit paradigm allows multiple libraries to co-exist in Qt, I re-downloaded the Qt 4.8 library, but it suffers from the same problem.  I have pointed Qt Creator to qmake for both the 4.8 and 5.0 libraries, but that doesn't seem to be the problem either.

I haven't been able to see evidence of anyone else running into such a crippling problem, so that suggests that I am missing something simple.  But even for being a newbie last summer, I felt I had gotten pretty comfortable with Qt, C++, and OpenGL from what I have managed to piece together from the Internet.

If anyone can nudge me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am willing to rebuild my application from scratch in Qt 5.0, but I can't use Qt at all at the moment.

Comment: Same problem for me. Appreciate help :)

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work!  In the directory /usr/bin/   there was more than one g++ executable.  They were labeled with different version numbers (g++-4.0, g++-4.2), but they showed up in Qt's automatic detection.  All I needed to do was delete the extras.  Leave only the g++ executable that is not labeled with a version number.  By limiting the options available to Qt, it automatically selected a compiler and now it works.

It is embarrassing that it took so long for me to find such a fast solution, but it is still a relief.  I hope others save time from my experience.